# Where is the right place to include a file when working with HTML & php

Tags: php, html, include

Where is the right place to include a file when working with HTML and php?

Before the HTML code:

```
<?php include 'file.php' ?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

In the head tag:

```
<html>
<head>
<?php include 'file.php' ?>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

In the body tag:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php include 'file.php' ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Depends on what's in your file.php. If it's a view/content, most likely within `<body>`. If it's system/app level function, at the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include the file wherever it would otherwise be in the code...

Example:
 - If the include is an html form, it would go in the body.
 - If the include is a php script to process the form, it would probably go in the head.

Comment: And if it includes some php functions?would you choose the head option or above the html tags option?

Comment: It depends what the script is for...If it's just php and there's no output (print or echo), then it really doesn't matter.  But if the php is generating content, then it needs to be where the content needs to be.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

If your imported file is just code with no characters outside the PHP blocks then it doesn't matter. I'd personally put it in the top of the file, so that I could use `ini_set` affecting the whole execution or send headers or cookies.

I you have content to be printed in the file's main code or outside PHP blocks you should put the file where you want the content.

Just noting, if you want keep the main HTML structure static in your main file and still want to print to both `<body>` and `<head>` I suggest you do both in functions, add the import to the file top and call the functions to print.

Answer (score 2):

PHP doesn't care where you put it.  For purposes of displaying your page, though, it depends on what is is the included file.  For example, if `file.php` contains the body of your table, obviously it should go in the `<body>` tag.

Comment: And if it includes some php functions?

Comment: It depends on what they do.  If it is only functions, call it before any other output -- this makes it easier to read and maintain, especially if you need to modify headers or cookies, as Pietu1998 pointed out.  But if it outputs something, put it wherever the output needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your need.

If your file.php file has some global functions that you'd like to access throughout your code, then I would say include it at the top. Additionally, if you're doing anything with the headers in the included file, definitely include it at the top.

However, say your file.php contains a dynamic javascript code (in other words a script that is changed by php depending on the situation), then the header is probably the best location for it, since that is more or less the standard location to place javascript.

Finally, if your file.php is meant to bring in actual html or structure to the file, then definitely include it in the body.